# How to enable java agent for every new java process on the host?

Tags: java, agent

I have a java agent that I want to be automatically enabled for any arbitrary java process running on the host.

I cannot rely on aliases or environment variables like `PATH`, `JVM_OPTS` etc as I want any JVM process to pick the agent even if run directly as `/usr/bin/java -jar my-app.jar`.

One (rather dirty) way of doing it is physically replacing `java` binary with my custom bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
$(dirname "$0")/java.original "-javaagent:path/to/my-agent.jar" "$@"
```

It works, but that approach requires renaming the original `java` binary file which I would like to avoid doing.

**Question**: Is there any better way how to achieve the same behavior without touching the `java` binary? Are there any global Java specific config file where I could instruct Java to *always* run with the given agent?

Comment: Is this a better fit for SO?

Comment: Possibly. Can the question be moved to SO somehow or should I re-create it there?

Comment: I don't have the power to move it, but feel free to crosspost and we can mark this as a duplicate or link the answer.

Comment: just flag your question on your own and it will be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable, that can be set in the `/etc/profile.d` for all users.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:path/to/my-agent.jar
```

Every java process will then pick it up, regardless the way it is started.

From the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html):

> This environment variable allows you to specify the initialization of tools, specifically the launching of native or Java programming language agents using the `-agentlib` or `-javaagent` options. In the following example the environment variable is set so that the HPROF profiler is launched when the application is started:

```
$ export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:hprof"
```

> This variable can also be used to augment the command line with other options for diagnostic purposes. For example, you can supply the -XX:OnError option to specify a script or command to be executed when a fatal error occurs.

There is also undocumented `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable that takes precedence over the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and the command line arguments, that might be handy in some cases. But because it's deprecated and might not be supported in all Java distributions it's not recommended to use.